# Avoiding ammending taxes for forthcoming 1099-R for 2011 when filing 2010 for IRA

Tags: united-states, excess-contribution, roth-conversion

I over contributed to my traditional IRA last year. This was then converted along with all my traditional IRAs into Roth IRAs in 2010. Then in 2011, I recharacterized the excess and earnings from Roth back to Traditional IRA and then did removal of excess contribution from my traditional IRA and used the excess as a 2011 contribution.

Now I'm doing my taxes and in Turbo-Tax, per their instructions, I manually entered a 1099-R for tax year 2011 with box 7 code P for the removal of excess distribution for the traditional IRA.

Now I'm stuck on the other part, the recharacterization of the excess and earnings from Roth to traditional.  I tried to manually enter a 1099-R for tax year 2011 with box 7 code R for the recharacterization, but on form 8606-T, line 16 does not reflect the reduced conversion due to the recharacterization.

I put the total of the excess contribution and its earnings amount in both box 1 and 2a and checked 2b taxable amount not determined to be consistent with the 1099-R for 2010 that had the Roth conversion box 7 code 2 and I did not check box for total distribution.

Is this a bug in Turbo-Tax, or have I entered the second form 1099-R for 2011 incorrectly?

Please suggest how to resolve, I'd rather not just override line 16 of form 8606-T and have Turbo-Tax compute the value correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd ask this over at the [TurboTax Live Community](https://ttlc.intuit.com/app/full_page?msid=int_hp_lc) after you file for extensions.  It seems to be frequented by people who work on the software and can tell you if it's a bug or not.